# Facing issue while retrieving value of a gatt service in android and then sending data to characteristic of that service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am very new BLE technology.I have declared the below service in **BluetoothLeService.java:**

```
public final static UUID UUID_SERV = UUID.fromString("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

I try to do a `getService()` for `UUID_SERV` :

```
BluetoothGattService gattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SERV);
```

The issue is that the `gattService` is showing null.I want to get `UUID_SERV` and its characteristics and then write the data to this characteristic.

```
public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("mBluetoothDeviceAddress======================" + mBluetoothDeviceAddress);
        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        System.out.println("mBluetoothGatt=============" + mBluetoothGatt);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        System.out.println("UUID_SERV======" + UUID_SERV);
        BluetoothGattService gattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SERV);
        System.out.println("gattService is===============" + gattService);
        if (gattService != null) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic = gattService.getCharacteristic(UUID_CHAR);
        }
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [discover services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) first, before you can retrieve them via that method.

> **public boolean discoverServices ()**
>
> Added in API level 18
>
> Discovers services offered by a remote device as
> well as their characteristics and descriptors.
>
> This is an asynchronous operation. Once service discovery is
> completed, the onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt, int) callback is
> triggered. If the discovery was successful, the remote services can be
> retrieved using the getServices() function.
>
> Requires BLUETOOTH permission.
>
> Returns true, if the remote service discovery has been started